# Installing and running 2048 game on android device for offline playing.

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I am trying to run 2048 game's android version at github (https://github.com/uberspot/2048-android ), for offline playing, but the game wont load correctly on a nexus-5 device. I have cloned the git and have a local copy saved on disk. After importing it as a local GIT project in eclipse, it compiles without any error but the game does not load correctly in the webview when testing it on device. Plain html content is displayed but the grid of tiles is absent.
Please share the correct way to import this git project into eclipse adt and the changes to be done in code in order to run it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an APK file on the root of the repository.
Download it and then install it on your device :

```
adb install ~/Download/2048.apk
```

It works on my Nexus 4 !

Comment: Thanks, I can run the app after installing the apk file. My aim is to re-skin this app, for which I want to be able to open it in eclipse. How can I import this git into eclipse so that I can modify it and then run it on my device?

Comment: Try to import it as an Android project and not as a Git project. 
As you can see, the project use a library (android-support). You have to add it in the build path of your project.